# NDSolve solution depends on time range

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages

I am solving the following ODE in Mathematica using NDSolve:

$$-dC_A/dt=k_sC_A^3+k_eC_A^2$$

where $k_s$ and $k_e$ are constants. The code I am using to solve the ODE is

```
s0 = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -ksc*a[t]^3 - kec*ccat*a[t]^2, a[0] == 2.5}, 
a, {t, 0, 2000}];
```

However, I have noticed that I get different results depending on when I end my time range. Specifically, I am solving

$$500=2.5/C_A(t)$$

for t.

If my time range goes to 2000, I get $t=4334.91$, but if my time range goes to 20,000, I get $t=17,705$. Any idea why this is occurring and which of the two is the correct result?

Edit: I've attached the code used to find t and parameter values.

```
NSolve[2.5/Evaluate[a[t] /. s0] == 500, t]
```

$k_s=0.2$ and $k_e=0.00825$

Comment: I'll assume `a[t]` in your code stands for $C_A$.  How do you solve $500=2.5/C_A(t)$?  If your maximum $t=2000$ in `NDSolve`, anything further would be extrapolation.

Comment: @ChrisK You assumption is correct. Sorry if I was not clear, but in the first case it goes to 2000, but in the second case I've changed the code to $t_{\text{end}}=20,000$.

Comment: Thanks. How do you solve $500=2.5/C_A(t)$?  Do you work on the `InterpolatingFunction` after the `NDSolve` or use a `WhenEvent`? Have you tried plotting the solution to see which answer is correct?

Comment: @ChrisK I've attached the code I'm using to solve for t. In regards to using a plot to determine which is the correct value, the plot also shows that the solution changes depending on the time scale.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without knowing the parameter values, but I'm pretty sure that the real answer occurs at $t=17705$ and the other one is based on extrapolation of your `InterpolatingFunction` outside the range it was defined on.

Comment: @ChrisK I've also edited the post to include the parameter values. I don't understand why you're leaning towards $t=17705$, could you possibly go into further detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you solve the differential equations to `tmax=2000`, the only way `s0` can go beyond that time is by extrapolation, which easily goes wild.  Look at this, where the valid solution is green and the extrapolated one is red:

```
ksc = 0.2;
kec = 0.00825;
ccat = 1;
tmax = 2000;
s0 = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -ksc*a[t]^3 - kec*ccat*a[t]^2, a[0] == 2.5}, a, {t, 0, tmax}];
Show[
  Plot[Evaluate[{500, 2.5/a[t] /. s0}], {t, 0, 2000}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}],
  Plot[Evaluate[{500, 2.5/a[t] /. s0}], {t, 2000, 20000}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20000}, {0, 600}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here we actually solve the differential equations for `tmax=20000`, which means no extrapolation is used:

```
tmax = 20000;
s0 = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -ksc*a[t]^3 - kec*ccat*a[t]^2, a[0] == 2.5}, a, {t, 0, tmax}];
Plot[Evaluate[{500, 2.5/a[t] /. s0}], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly the real answer is around $t=17700$.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Completely makes sense now.